# Regex object isn't locating a certain string

Tags: python

I am trying to parse specific data out of SEC filings, and I am in the process of the cleaning out extraneous information from the .txt file version of said forms. I am using a re.compile object and then using re.sub to replace strings identified by the re.compile object with a single space.

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1848898/000119312521068620/0001193125-21-068620.txt'
response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'placeholder@emailaddress.com'}).text

formatted_response = response.replace('\n',' ').replace('\t',' ')

underwriters_begin = formatted_response[re.search(r'<B>Underwriters</B>|<B>Underwriter</B>|Underwriter<\/FONT>', formatted_response).span()[0]:]
underwriters_text = underwriters_begin[:re.search(r'\d+,\d+,\d+', underwriters_begin).span()[1]]

cleaner = re.compile('\s{2,}|<.*?>|&\S+|Underwriter\w*|Total|Number\s*of\s*Units')

clean_text = re.sub(cleaner, ' ', underwriters_text)

clean_text
```

The output is:

['           Number of Units           Cantor Fitzgerald  Co.                                                         20,000,000'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdpeN.png)

I am curious why the "\s{2,}" part of the re.compile object is not replacing sections of the text with 2 or more spaces, and similarly, while the "Number of Units" text is not removed. Is this some issue with text encoding?

Note: I am a pretty junior programmer, so this will need a sort of ELI5 answer, if possible. Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: Don't know if this is the only problem, but you need to pass a `raw` string inthe statement  re.compile( - like this  `cleaner = re.compile(r'\s{2,}|<.*?>|&\....`

Comment: Thank you! I did notice one other thing, however. Because this .txt file is formatted with HTML tags (thus why I do a replace on "<.*?>" strings), I actually remove a <BR> tag between "of" and "Units". In some files, this is <BR>, in others it is<br>. I think I need some sort of catch all, and I am struggling to find the right order of operations in my call to the sub method.